# Disabling maven site plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am having issues in disabling maven site plugin all together from maven release lifecycle phase.

Basically if maven site plugin v3.5.1 is used with Maven 3.3.0 and above - it complains about

```
org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.CiManagementReport
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent
```

After searching online - the suggestion I receive is to use v3.7.1 of the maven site along with v3.0.0 of maven report plugin but I am facing with issues during the release phase.

Wagon protocol 'https' doesn't support directory copying -> ...

My question is - what is the proper way to disable the maven site plugin. I have tried from maven command line using -D

```
maven.site.skip=true (skips generating site)
maven.site.deploy.skip=true (skips site deployment)
```

and also plugin parameters in pom.

Is there any other viable solution?

Comment: First why are you using such an old Maven version (3.3.0? Apart from that 3.3.0 does not exist ... ) also why using such an old maven-site-plugin version ... also why using wagon for directory copying? Can you post your pom file ? And a full log file would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by disabling the Maven doc plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <arguments>-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true</arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```